# How to customize the statistical result from proc arima in SAS

Tags: sas, proc

I have a time series data set, I want to customize the output, which means I only want some statistical values from specific result in the result window.

What I want to get is just to get the values of 'Zero Mean' from the table call Augmented Dickey-Fuller Unit Root Tests. And remove all the other types in this table.

The code is below:

```
DATA ts;
Process='II Trend';
DO nsam=1 TO 1000;
SEED=1564646+nsam;
a0=2;
a2=0.8;
DO i=1 TO 200;
error=RANNOR(SEED);
y= a0 + i*a2 + error;
IF i>100 THEN OUTPUT;
END;
END;
RUN;

PROC ARIMA DATA=ts;
IDENTIFY VAR=y 
STATIONARITY=(ADF=(3));
RUN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you're best bet is to capture the tables and print them out, assuming there isn't an option to control them. I'm assuming you've read the docs to that effect:

```
ods listing close;
ods table StationarityTests=zero_mean(where=(Type="Zero Mean"));
PROC ARIMA DATA=ts;
IDENTIFY VAR=y 
STATIONARITY=(ADF=(3));
RUN;quit;
ods listing;
proc print data=Zero_Mean noobs label;
run;
```